# Get Brush from Color without SolidColorBrush

Tags: c#, windows, drawing

It looks like the [SolidColorBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.aspx) requires .NET 3 or up, and I have a requirement to keep away from requiring manufacturing computers go through an upgrade.

So, given a [System.Drawing.Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx) `color`, how would I create a [System.Drawing.Brush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.brush.aspx)?

```
public static Brush GetBrush(Color color) {
  Brush result = Brushes.Black;
  // What goes here?
  return result;
}
```

The only static methods I see in Brushes are `Equals` and `ReferenceEquals`; non-static is only `Clone`.

**EDIT:** (Resolved - thanks [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks))

Using [System.Drawing.SolidBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.solidbrush.aspx), I am able to write:

```
public static Brush GetBrush(Color color) {
  if (color != Color.Empty) {
    return new SolidBrush(color);
  }
  return Brushes.Black;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing the WPF SolidColorBrush.
WPF itself is new to .Net 3.0.

The GDI+ (System.Drawing) [`SolidBrush` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.solidbrush.aspx) has always existed.